# Отключить отображение ререндера

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Мне нужно отключить отображение вот этих желтых квадратов. Как я понял, они показывают, что элемент перерисовался. Я когда то его включил и уже забыл где и теперь не помню как выключить :) Не подскажете как? :). Браузер хром

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Средства разработчика F12 -> три точки возле кнопки закрытия -> more tools -> rendering. И там пара похожих птичек.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev что за "пара похожих птичек"? Я вроде все перетыкал, проблема не решилась)

Comment: Открой в devtools `⋮` ► More tools ► Rendering, и там в первом (верхнем) блоке опций сними все галочки. Что именно у тебя не получается в этих действиях? Опиши затруднения подробнее.

Comment: @yar85 Да да, я все отключил. "Квадраты" не исчезли

Comment: @yar85 Я в вопросе прикрепил доп. скрин

Comment: А в режиме инкогнито проблема повторяется?

Comment: @yar85 нет, не повторяется

Comment: Значит, вероятнее что эту обводку добавляет какое-то браузерное расширение, а не devtools. Стоит проверить такой вариант. В крайнем случае, можно удалить профиль браузера и создать новый (синхронизация сохранит закладки-пароли, но вот расширения без интеграции с гуглосинком, настраивать придется заново).

Comment: @yar85 хмм, очень странно. Но я проверил это в другом профиле хром, без расширений и да, там нет обводки, так что проблема все таки в расширениях. Попробую по очереди их отключать. Дам знать о результате позже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Попробуй вот тут снять галку, но это вроде только в том случае еcли стоит ReactDevTools

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна вкладка `Customize and control Dev Tools` -> `More tools` -> `Rendering`.

[image]